# Rails action view form helper "f.email_field" not showing same formatting as other helpers on the same page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, helper

I have the following code:

```
<div class="skinny_wrapper wrapper_padding">
  <%= form_for @contact do |f| %>
  <%= f.label :name %> <br>
  <%= f.text_field :name, required: true %>

  <br>

  <%= f.label :email %> <br>
  <%= f.email_field :email, required: true %>

  <br>

  <%= f.label :message %> <br>
  <%= f.text_area :message, as: :text %>

  <div class="hidden">
    <%= f.label :nickname %> <br>
    <%= f.text_field :nickname, hint: "leave this field blank" %>
  </div>

  <%= f.submit "Send Message", class: "button" %>

  <% end %>
</div>
```

The email input field is not taking the same formatting as the other fields, and is displaying as follows:

[Email form issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9DVxD.png)

I'm not sure why this is happening.

The "skinny_wrapper" and "wrapper_padding" classes contain the following CSS:

```
.skinny_wrapper {
width: 80%;
max-width: 760px;
margin: 0 auto;
}

.wrapper_padding {
padding: 1.8rem 0;
}
```

Comment: Probably a CSS issue. What does the classes `skinny_wrapper` and `wrapper_padding` contain? Update the question with the code.

Comment: @Pavan I updated it here. Just not sure why it is displaying differently when it's all in the same div? Thanks for your help!

Comment: put <%= f.text_field :email, required: true %> instead of email field!

Comment: @nourza if I do this then the neat email validation, which prompts users to enter an email address with an @ symbol etc, doesn't work.

Comment: Inspect the email field in the browser console. Check whether any other CSS messing with it.

Comment: There is some other CSS applied to it:
`input {
    -webkit-appearance: textfield;
    background-color: white;
    -webkit-rtl-ordering: logical;
    cursor: text;
    padding: 1px;
    border-width: 2px;
    border-style: inset;
    border-color: initial;
    border-image: initial;
}` 
I'm not sure where this is coming from, as I can't find that exact code in my code. (I'm a beginner :) )

Comment: well, that could be the code that is breaking your email field styling. Try via web console to tick off some of that code and see how it is impacting your email field style.

Comment: @JohnBaker it is what is impacting the email box. I can't tick it off to see what it looks like without that styling, but I also have no idea where it came from or why it is applied and cannot be removed.

Answer (score 0):

```
.skinny_wrapper{
    position:relative;
   }
 .skinny_wrapper input[type="text"],input[type="email"],.skinny_wrapper textarea{
    width: 80%;
    max-width: 760px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    display:block; 
    }

    .wrapper_padding input[type="text"],input[type="email"],.wrapper_padding textarea{
    padding: 1.8rem 0; 
    }
```

Try this and let me know what you got!

Comment: This didn't work, it changed the dimensions of the wrapper so that the top two fields are pushed far to the left and don't take up the entire width, and the message field does take up the entire width :(

Comment: nope that doesn't work either, the email entry box is now huge and the password box looks the same as the email box did before.